# Problema al usar XAMPP - Ayuda

Tags: xampp, error404

> Solucion a este problema - [Aqúi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22058569/5587982)

Hola gente de stackoverflow tengo un problema con mi servidor local XAMPP la cosa es asi cualdo incio me salen estos mensajes en la consola, pero ayer me salian pero no tenia problemas en el navegador pero hoy si en el navegador dice:**Este sitio web no puede proporcionar una conexión segura
localhost ha enviado una respuesta no válida.**

Bueno espero que me ayuden con este problema y necesito treminar algo pero no puedo

> NOTA ya he cambiado el porto a **localhost:8080**

[image]

> **y en el navegador sale esto**

[image]

Comment: El mensaje en color azul te dice que debes tener derechos de administrador para correr el programa. ¿Has probado con una cuenta administrador?

Comment: cambia el puerto en que se ejecutando apache ya que el puerto **80** ya esta en uso.

Comment: A.Cedano si ya lo hice pero nada

Comment: @Efrain si lo se pensé y cambie el puerto a 8080 eso solo me funciono 2 días pero ahora ya no

Comment: Verifica lo que dice [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22058569/5587982).

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias despues de un rato funciono bien